# Get the most out of high performance MDB

Tags: performance, transactions, application-server, message-driven-bean

Application server creates a new transaction before calling MDB's onMessage method. Also I am processing database update in onMessage method. Transactions create additional overhead and processing several message in one transaction could increase performance.

Is it possible to make App server to use one transaction for several messages. Or maybe there are other approaches to this problem?

And, by the way, I can't use multiple instances, cause I need to preserve the sequence order.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can store the messages in a list and depending upon how many messages you want to process in one transaction you can check the size of the list and process the messages.